# How do I make the box smaller in html?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

In my code, I have a drop-down menu. However, the grey box extends to the end of the screen. How can I limit the grey box?

Code from here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/7rsznauv

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="cf">
        <li><a class="dropdown" href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-menu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul {
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFF;
    background: #ddd;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
nav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 25%;
}
nav a {
    background: #ddd;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    font: bold 16px/50px sans-serif;
    padding: 0 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease;
            transition: all .25s ease;
}
nav .dropdown:after {
    content: ' ▶';
}
nav .dropdown:hover:after{
    content:'\25bc'
}
nav li:hover a {
    background: #ccc;
}
nav li ul {
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
         -o-transition: all .25s ease;
            transition: all .25s ease;
}
nav li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 50px;
    visibility: visible;
}
nav li ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
nav li ul a:hover {
    background: #bbb;
}

/* Clearfix */

.cf:after, .cf:before {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear:both;
}
.cf {
    zoom:1;
}​
```

Comment: You have linked your code twice. Please remove one of the links

Comment: Here you go: http://cssdeck.com/labs/pmrcasw2

Comment: To @Andrew Barber, my code is in the cssdeck website... please read the question before you mark it as "not including a minimal example"

Comment: @aj8uppal - SO questions hould stand on their own.  Links should be to help get the message across, but not necersarry.

Comment: I just didn't want to make the question too wordy... is that wrong?

Comment: @aj8uppal - You definitely want the minimum code to reproduce the problem.  Read this for some hints: https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: I've imported the code from your link, and cast the last vote to reopen. In the future, it's a good idea to do that - although you may also want to consider trying to narrow down the code as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nav ul {
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFF;
    background: #ddd;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 90%; // I made it 90% you can make it even narrower
}
```

Just reduce the width by reducing the percentage or like     `width: 180px;`

Answer (score 0):

just change the `width` in `hnav ul{....}`, actually is 100%, change it to 50% or whatever you want

Comment: You just copied my answer and added a typo

Comment: LOL i didn't see your answer until posted my own, there is no problem friend i can remove it we are here to help others i think :D

Comment: I am sorry, no need to delete it :D